# Any way to obtain an even bigger mouse cursor in linux?

Tags: linux, xfce, mouse, manjaro, theme

Here is the size of my current mouse cursor...

[image]

which is already at the highest setting (48). As you can see here:

[image]

However I would really like to be able to increase this setting and go beyond (48), to say (256) or something, like this example below I made in GIMP...

[image]

It seems like such an easy and simple task yet I have also tried setting the cursor theme size to 148 within ***Settings Editor*** but no success, it did absolutely nothing at all...

[image]

---

Any other ways to increase the cursor size? Anything?

Comment: There are sometimes limitations for the cursor size of you have the "hardware cursor" settings for your X driver enabled. In general, the X cursor is a glyph from a font, so by making your own fonts you should be able to get larger cursors. I have no idea how this meshes with Manjaro's "settings", and how these translate into the calls the set the cursor in X applications.